# BufferedOutputStream not throwing I/O exception

Tags: java, file-io, fileoutputstream, bufferedinputstream

While working on `BufferedOutputStream` found it does not throw an `IOException` when we wrote on it after closing the stream.

To verify my result, i checked `FileOutputStream` found it is throwing `IOException` once we try to write on it after closing it.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Created a byte[] barry1 barry2
            byte[] barry1 = { '1', '3' };
            byte[] barray2 = { '2', '4' };
            OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(
                  new FileOutputStream("abc.txt", false));
            // Writing to stream
            os.write(barry1);
            os.close();
            os.write(barray2); // this suceeds - bug

            os = new FileOutputStream("abc.txt", true);
             //Writing to stream
            os.write(barry1);
            os.close();
            os.write(barray2); // crashes here, correct.
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Could some one help me on this, Why this behavior is different ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> While working on BufferedOutputStream found it does not throw an IOException when we wrote on it after closing the stream.

The `BufferedOutputStream` code just doesn't have that sort of checking – but then neither does the `FileOutputStream`.  In both cases, only when the IO is actually written to disk does the OS "throw" the `IOException`.  It is not the Java code which is detecting that the stream has been closed.  As an aside, this probably means that some native implementations don't throw at all.

The reason why the `FileOutputStream` is throwing the exception on `os.write(...)`, versus the `BufferedOutputStream`, is that it is writing the IO to the underlying native layer immediately.  If you add a `os.flush()` call to the `BufferedOutputStream` after the `os.write()` then you will see the same exception because that forces its internal buffer to be written out.

```
OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("abc.txt", false));
os.write(barry1);
os.close();
os.write(barray2); // this suceeds – unfortunate behavior
os.flush();  // adding this line throws an IOException
```

In looking at the `BufferedOutputStream`'s `close()` method (actually in the `FilterOutputStream` base class), you can see that the output stream is not set to `null` or anything:

```
public void close() throws IOException {
    try {
      flush();
    } catch (IOException ignored) {
    }
    out.close();
}
```

I also don't like the fact that it is ignoring IOExceptions on close here.  Wow.  This tells me that we should always call `flush()` by hand before `close()` which is a pattern I specifically don't do.

Now compare that code to the `BufferedWriter.close()`:

```
public void close() throws IOException {
    synchronized (lock) {
        if (out == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            flushBuffer();
        } finally {
            out.close();
            out = null;   // good doggie
            cb = null;
        }
    }
}
```

`BufferedWriter.close()` doesn't eat the exception and sets the delegated `Writer` to be `null`.  Much better IMO.

Comment: +1 to this answer. I had same doubt until I tried to call outputsteam.flush(). That call immediately threw IOException when outputstream is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Because `BufferedOutputStream` writes bytes to its **internal byte buffer**, then **when invoked writes to the underlying ouput stream**, so if call flush after the `os.write(c);`, it will throw the exception, but here you try to write to the file stream directly after it was closed, hence the exception, no surprise here

Comment: No, I think it's still surprising that writing to the `BufferedOutputStream` when *that* is closed (not the `FileOutputStream`) doesn't throw an exception. I could understand if the OP were closing the `FileOutputStream` underneath, but I'd expect `BufferedOutputStream` to have a check as well.

Comment: Woow a favour comment  from @JonSkeet ... :) Sir please check

Answer (score 0):

After checking the JDK code found that `ensureOpen()` method that throws an IOException with a detail message of "Stream closed"is missing in BufferedOutputStream. From my understanding this must be there.